# Comparing a value in a cell to values in a range copying adjacent cell if match is found

Tags: excel, compare, vlookup

Hope someone can help as I keep finding similar answers but nothing quite fits my requirement.

I have 2 sheets, sheet 1 has 2 columns.....

A has ID's (long codes with no's, letters and symbols)
B has a value corresponding to each of the ID'S

Sheet 2 has multiple Columns detailing items with corresponding ID's.

A has item description
B has ID
C is blank

I want to populate C with the relevant data from Sheet 1 column B into column C whenever the ID's match

Any help would be great as this could save me hours of work

Comment: You tagged this as `VLOOKUP` which is what I would recommended.  What have you tried?  And how is it not working?

Comment: Thanks Byron, I have managed to sort it now by creating a table with the data I needed to reference. I was using VLOOKUP but my data range would not work. This was probably due to it's position in my actual spread sheet (i.e. not the leftmost column)

Comment: sorry, I'm new to this

Answer (score 1):

In sheet 1 I highlighted all of the data and selected  I then named it table1. I then went to the top of Sheet 2 column B and chose fx VLOOKUP & selected Sheet 2 A2 as Lookup Value, table1 as Table Array, 2 as Col Index No. and False as the Range Lookup. My formula looked like this: VLOOKUP(A2,Table1,2,FALSE)